# "Muchos gracias" o "Mucho gracias", ¿cuál es correcto?

Tags: expresiones, saludos

Estudio español en mi escuela y no sé qué es correcto decir a mis amigos y profesores. Normalmente digo "Muchos gracias".

¿De hecho hay alguna diferencia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo correcto es *muchas gracias*. En español, el adjetivo debe concordar en género y número con el sustantivo. Como *gracias* es femenino plural, el adjetivo (en este caso, *muchas*) también debe estar en femenino plural.

Comment: Gracias por tu responder

Comment: Las gracias --> muchas gracias.